# Entire email link displayed in RichTextBox control

Tags: asp.net, winforms

Windows Application, 3.5 Framework:

I have a FAQ page that has a RichTextBox control taking up the bulk of the page.  The client supplied a Word Document with multiple email addresses based on the topic.  In Word this renders correctly (only displaying the Text To Display part of the Hyperlink).
When this is rendered in the Control all data pertaining to the link is shown

> What I'm looking for : Help@Company.com 
>   What I'm getting : Help@Company.com <mailto:Help@Company.com?subject=SystemSupport>

I have handled all events and this IS WORKING as far as generating emails using the following code:

```
    private void lnkHelp_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.TopMost = false;            
        string href = e.LinkText + "?Subject= SystemSupport";
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(href);
    }
```

It just looks very bad, especially with their long long long email addresses.

Thanks in advance:

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing myself. Did you ever find a solution for this?